# Migrating data from a JSONfield to individual fields

Tags: django

I have a DJango Model class in which it was decided to store a bunch of data in a blob form. The reasons for this decission are not clear to me ... Regardless I now have the task of converting that JSONField into individual Model fields. My question is, how would I go about creating a custom DJango migration that would extract the data from the JSONField and migrate it into the new fields?

My first idea is to make a migration in which I add all the new fields, then a second migration that will be custom made. In this second one I will use the django orm to go through every instance of my model and extract the JSON data and then loop through the field structure and alter the newly added fields with the JSON values. The only issue that I could see is if the fields have special constrants then it would get pretty tedious to get everything wright.

Any suggestions on my approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you described is the way to go. Its always an annoying job to migrate data over from a table to another. Like you said, create the models you need in a single migration, then write a custom one to dump the data in your `JSONfield` into the new tables and then delete the field.

Adding validation for "special constrains" is key, so you may need to give it a few tries. If the migration fails, it will simply revert, so if you need to push this to production then you find an unexpected error with your second migration, make sure you have logging, check the logging, adjust your migration and try again.

Another tip is that I would make sure the first migration (adding the new table) is migrated properly before creating the second one.